# When did toons come to life?

Tags: movie, cartoon, who-framed-roger-rabbit

*Who Framed Roger Rabbit* had toons and people living together. Now my question is this: when did toons and people start living in the living universe or did humans start living in the toon universe instead?
I would like to know if there’s a in-universe answer if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the film's source novel ([Who Censored Roger Rabbit?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Censored_Roger_Rabbit%3F)) there's every indication that toons have been around as long as regular humans. There's some speculation that toons and humans are both offshoots of the same evolutionary tree.

> Had the DeGreasy boys been discovered frozen beneath some Arctic
>   tundra, a good case would probably have been made for their being **the
>   long-sought missing link between humans and Toons.**

and

> "Not particularly. No more so than I imagine it might be for you to
>   throw one of your fingernail clippings into a trash can. Oh, I'm sure
>   there are primitive tribes in Africa or somewhere who treat their
>   doppelgangers as mystic offshoots of their soul, but we modern,
>   civilized Toons regard our doppelgangers as animated mannequins,
>   nothing more."

---

Toons appear to be well established in both pre-colonial America and in large numbers in Indo-China.

> His great-great-great had crossed over from the old country on board
>   the Mayflower and had been the guy who arranged to have the nation's
>   first Thanksgiving dinner catered by the Toons the colonists found
>   living here. For this Jess's ancestor got his name in the history
>   books. Another of Jess's relatives had imported thousands of Toons
>   from China to build the nation's first transcontinental railroad. They
>   became known as the Yellow Kids and won that relative a spot in the
>   history books, too.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have the book on hand.

Comment: TIL Who Framed Roger Rabbit had a source novel.

Comment: @zabeus - It's worth a read. It's very similar right up to the point that it suddenly isn't.

Answer (score 8):

As best I can tell paging through the material online, there is no indication the Toons haven't always been there, side by side with humanity, as second class citizens. This jibes with the book it was based on, *Who Censored Roger Rabbit?*.

Comment: This answer seems to lack referencing. What material online, what does it say in the book, etc etc

Comment: You are right. I'll cite my sources, scarce as they are. Yours is the better answer. Mine just happened to be there earlier. :)

Comment: How does this work with Jessica's statement "I'm not bad I'm just drawn this way." Or Betty Boop saying life has been hard since things went to color?

Comment: @JackBNimble Probably that toons are somehow born from the human psyche as a side-effect of artistic expression sparking into independent sapience... which makes me wonder what pre-Columbian toons looked like, given the kinds of artwork they produced.

Comment: I think "drawn this way" might just be a metaphor.

Comment: Perhaps they have a deistic belief system which centres around a "great artist", that they were drawn into existence. Perhaps a toon saying they are "drawn this way" is the same as a creationist human saying "it's the way I'm made".

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It could even be used to tie into some of the self-imposed stereotypes ethnic groups alternately reject and embrace. "Honey, I can't help how much I drink. I'm Irish." "What, not move my hands when I'm speaking? I'm Italian, you dolt!"

Answer (score 5):

I believe in the book there is a single sentence about Columbus encountering toons for the first time when he landed in North America.

That doesn't really explain much but the story just runs with it.

Comment: This coincides with my memory of the book. The toons and Indians inhabited the Americas. Historically Columbus never landed in North America. Parts of central and South America in his later voyages, but he never made it to the Northern continent.

Comment: It wasn't Columbus, it was the Mayflower arrivals.